# Ubuntu щелчки в наушниках

Tags: ubuntu, аудио

Перед тем как воспроизводится звук происходит щелчок в наушниках. Встроенные динамики в ноутбуке так себя не ведут. Я пробовал подключать другое устройство воспроизведения (колонки) работают так же как и наушники. То есть проблема в ноутбуке или в ОС.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В последних версиях Ubuntu усилен акцент на экономию заряда батареи и многие устройства (в том числе и звуковая карта) автоматически отключаются при бездействии. Поэтому, перед началом воспроизведения происходит включение адаптера, которое часто сопровождается щелчком.

Отключить режим экономии для звуковой карты можно добавив в файл `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` следующую строку:

```
options snd-hda-intel power_save=0 power_save_controller=N
```

[Подробное описание проблемы](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/hd-audio/notes.html#power-saving) на английском.

Answer (score 1):

Установите параллельно какую-нибудь ОС или используйте live-дистрибутив и проверьте на нем будут ли посторонние шумы?
Если щелчки не программные - значит механические, что-то внутри или рядом с ноутбуком создает помехи (проверить все подключаемые устройства). Я бы попробовал разобрать ноутбук, почистил все от пыли, проверил все шлейфы (вытащил и воткнул вновь).

Comment: не, это всё-таки из-за экономии батареи